# Inconsistent behaviour of Pandas groupby with pd.Series.mode

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate

This works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                   'key': [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]})
df.groupby('key')['A'].agg(pd.Series.mode)


key
0              A0
1              A1
2              A2
3    [A3, A4, A5]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

While making the values in A integers, I get the following error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [12, 23, 45, 2, 87, 56],
                   'key': [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]})

df.groupby('key')['A'].agg(pd.Series.mode)


ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
```

Comment: `pd. __version__`  = 1.1.5

Comment: FWIW, both codes run without error in pandas 1.5.2

Comment: @mozway then why are you saying "it's expected"?

Comment: Sorry I realize the phrasing was unclear, I meant it was/is a described issue, depending on the version. [Here is a reference](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25581)